# Lodash orderBy not ordering the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sql-order-by, lodash

Functionality part of a react application, using redux.
I implemented the filtering and sorting for a product catalog in a redux selector. 
OrderBy is not returning the sorted array. The selector calls the ordering function; however, the returned results aren't sorted.

```js
export const _sortingDestinations = (destinations,properties ) =>
{

    window.destinations = destinations
    window.orderBy = _.orderBy

    const sorted = _.orderBy( destinations,[ 'name' ],[  'asc' ] )
    console.log("Original", destinations)
    console.log("sorted", sorted)
    return  sorted

}
```

```js
//This function is called by the following redux selector

const getCatalogList = state => state.catalog.list
const getFilter = state => state.filter
const getSort = state => state.sort

export default createSelector(
    getCatalogList,
    getFilter,
    getSort,
    (items,filter,sort) => _sortingDestinations(_.filter( 
        _.map(items, o => WindPoint(o,filter)),
        ( o ) => DestinationFilter( o,filter ) ),sort)
)
```

The console logs:

```js
Original:
0: {name: "Beauduc", country: "France", airport: "MRS", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
1: {name: "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", country: "Australia", airport: "CCK", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
2: {name: "Fuerteventura", country: "Spain", airport: "FUE", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
3: {name: "Moorea", country: "French Polynesia", airport: "MOZ", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
4: {name: "Rarotonga", country: "Cook Islands", airport: "RAR", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
5: {name: "Roatan", country: "Honduras", airport: "RTB", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
6: {name: "Taveuni Island", country: "Fiji", airport: "TVU", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
7: {name: "Vanuatu", country: "Fiji", airport: "VLI", youtubeLink: null, _rawDescription: null, …}
8: {name: "Whitsunday Islands", country: "Australia", airport: "HTI", yout

Sorted:
0: {name: "Roatan", country: "Honduras", airport: "RTB", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
1: {name: "Taveuni Island", country: "Fiji", airport: "TVU", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
2: {name: "Fuerteventura", country: "Spain", airport: "FUE", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
3: {name: "Beauduc", country: "France", airport: "MRS", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
4: {name: "Whitsunday Islands", country: "Australia", airport: "HTI", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
5: {name: "Vanuatu", country: "Fiji", airport: "VLI", youtubeLink: null, _rawDescription: null, …}
6: {name: "Rarotonga", country: "Cook Islands", airport: "RAR", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
7: {name: "Moorea", country: "French Polynesia", airport: "MOZ", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
8: {name: "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", country: "Australia", airport: "CCK"
```

If I run the same code in the Chrome console I obtain the desired results:

```js
orderBy(destinations,['name'],['asc'])
0: {name: "Beauduc", country: "France", airport: "MRS", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
1: {name: "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", country: "Australia", airport: "CCK", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
2: {name: "Fuerteventura", country: "Spain", airport: "FUE", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
3: {name: "Moorea", country: "French Polynesia", airport: "MOZ", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
4: {name: "Rarotonga", country: "Cook Islands", airport: "RAR", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
5: {name: "Roatan", country: "Honduras", airport: "RTB", youtubeLink: Array(4), _rawDescription: null, …}
6: {name: "Taveuni Island", country: "Fiji", airport: "TVU", youtubeLink: Array(2), _rawDescription: null, …}
7: {name: "Vanuatu", country: "Fiji", airport: "VLI", youtubeLink: null, _rawDescription: null, …}
8: {name: "Whitsunday Islands", country: "Australia", airport: "HTI", youtu
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/jeqacigilu/edit?js,console)

Comment: "*f I run the same code in the Chrome console*" wait, where are you running the initial one, then?

Comment: It is part of a bigger application, the code is running in a redux selector to sort our catalog products.

Comment: Check what you're returning?

Comment: @MonteCristo I am doing it by oggin the results

Comment: what is `getSort`? you should make it more readable. then you can see where it's going wrong. It seems `_.filter` not closing properly?

Comment: @MonteCristo Code Actually that why I did not post all code at the beginning. The code is running perfectly. 

getSort is a selector function, I am just using exact same notation given by reselect

 what I do not understand is why orderBy is returning these results.

Comment: Your `_sortingDestinations` you posted don't work. there are functions that are undefined. May be you have them in your app. so check those sorting functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209793/discussion-between-muntram-van-chen-and-montecristo).